# What is the name of the noun to verb transformation?

Tags: terminology

What is the name of the grammatical transformation that consists in creating a verb from a noun?

Comment: Is the term 'verbalisation'' what you're looking for?

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics.SE! This is a pretty valid question, but it seems to attract downvotes — probably due to the lack of own research prior to asking. Have you done any? If so, please add your results here, with sample words and so on. This would improve the quality of this question and encourage others to answer it.

Answer (score 4):

The term you're looking for is **denominal verbalization**.

Comment: and wouldn't this be a form of *derivation*?

Comment: Yes, any affix that changes POS is considered derivational morphology, even if the affix is Zero. Also called [_Verbing_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Verbing.pdf), at least to Calvin and Hobbes readers.

Answer (score 1):

This is called derivational morphological process as well as verbalisation after attached and some affixes (bound morphemes). see Derivational affixes.

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics.SE! This post would benefit from citing relevant works and linking to credible resources. Don't just give a one-line answer, making others to search for mentioned terms.